# How to get how many tokens are left to mint from an ERC721 smart contract that implements a max supply?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, interfaces, totalsupply

I have an ERC721 that implements a `public maxSupply` value, so I cannot `mint` more than a certain amount of tokens.

Thanks to the `public` modifier, this exposes a method I can call to see what the `maxSupply` is.

I can then perform `maxSupply` - `totalSupply` (considering that my `ERC721` implements `ERC721Enumerable` extension as well) to know how many tokens are left to mint.

But, as I understand, the `maxSupply` function is not part of the `IERC721` nor the `IERC721Enumerable` interfaces.

Does this mean that if I want to call this method from another smart contract I should create my own interface?

Comment: create my own interface? yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, If you want to interact with the `maxSupply` function from another smart contract, you should create your own custom interface.
Here's an example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Enumerable.sol";

interface ICustomERC721 is IERC721Enumerable {
    function maxSupply() external view returns (uint256);
}
```